# Live video streaming without using flash?

Tags: video-streaming, videochat

Is there any way to implement something similar to [Chatroulette](http://chatroulette.com) without using Flash or Silverlight?

No, the yet-to-be-implemented-but-very-nice-to-have [HTML5 Stream API](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#stream-api) is not a valid answer. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we disregard Flash and Silverlight, the only reasonable things that come to mind are Java applets (please, please do not do this), custom browser plugins (an awful lot of work, and who would want to install a plugin just to use Chatroulette...) and just using the `<object>` element and relying on whatever media player the user may or may not have installed (this will not give you very good control over much anything).

All in all, I wouldn't say it's feasible to do without using one of the aforementioned, reasonably wide-spread plugins.

Comment: @amn: Nobody has Java enabled in the browser due to repeated security problems. Besides the JVM spinning up freezes even a reasonably good computer for a while when loading your page. Plus I've yet to see a good-looking Java applet. Need I go on?